# Check if element contains class then remove class

Tags: javascript

I can't implement the check function `if (element.classList.contains(__active))`. That is, if the element already contains the class "active", then you need to remove this class from the element when you click on it.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pavel_zolotin/pen/podqBLM)

Comment: Code should be posted **here**. Stack Overflow has facilities for making runnable code snippets.

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pavel_zolotin/pen/podqBLM)

Comment: @Paffly -- **Again**, as Pointy said, the code should be **here**, not (just) offsite and linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: You can just call element.classList.remove('className')
If element contains that class it will be removed, if not nothing will happen. You can also use element.classList.toggle('className') which will remove class if exists, and add class if it not exists

Answer (score 2):

You can remove without checking. Try this:

```js
const clickHandler = () => {
  document.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
};
```

```css
div {
  color: red;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 16px
}

div.active {
  color: black;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">CHNAGE ME</div>
<button onClick="clickHandler()">CLICK TO CHANGE</button>
```